# An etale morphism to a separated scheme is affine?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-stacks

I see the following statement in the proof of the local structure theorem of DM stacks from Jarod Alper's notes (Theorem 4.2.1).
[image]

My question is why an etale from an affine scheme to a separated scheme is affine. Furthermore, is such an etale morphism still affine if $U$ is not affine or $\mathfrak{X}$ is only quasi-separated?

I tried to prove the statement by using the cohomological criterion for affineness or by assuming the morphism $U\to\mathfrak{X}$ is standard etale. But neither seems to give a proof in an obvious way.

Comment: Maybe this is an application of Zariski's main theorem? Your morphism is a composition of an open embedding and a finite map, and your hypotheses should imply that the open embedding is also affine.

Answer (score 0):

I do not have enough reputation to write a comment so I will write it as an answer. Any morphism from an affine scheme to a stack with affine diagonal is affine. I believe you can find a proof on the stacks project. A separated DM stack has finite diagonal.